# Partition vector

Tags: partitions

I have a vector composed of 10 elements and I want to "split" it into two vectors composed of five elements:

```
q={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};Partition[q,5]
```

but the output is a matrix...

```
{{1,2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9,10}}
```

How can I obtain 2 separated vectors rather than a matrix?

Comment: What are 'two separated vectors'? `Sequence @@ Partition[q,5]`? It will still have `Sequence` head but that is the closest concept I suppose.

Comment: @tomd:  Huh?  Doesn't your answer give precisely what the poser's (unsatisfactory) answer gives?

Comment: Don't think of it as a matrix, think of it as a list of vectors. You can do [[1]] or //First or any other list operation to extract the first and second vectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output of a line of *Mathematica* code is a single element, so

```
Partition[q,5]
```

is all you can get.  If you want to access the parts individually:

```
Partition[q,5][[1]]
```

and

```
Partition[q,5][[2]]
```

What exactly do you want this for?  (That will help us help you.)

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
q = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
{part1, part2} = Partition[q,5]
```

Now you have two separate lists (part1 and part2), each containing half of the partitioned q.